# Symfony2 - How to enable registering with email only using FOSUserBundle?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using FOSUserBundle.

it requires both email address and userID for registration.

But I want to use email address for userID.

I can enable the email login as instructed [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/logging_by_username_or_email.md).

If I somply delete the form for userID in twig ,it doesn’t submit the pages.

How can I solve this? Which class can I handle the process before newuser creation?

I simplified the source to get only email and pasword.

it shows this script.

```
<form action="/myapp/web/app_dev.php/register/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" class="fos_user_registration_register">   
<div class="itemBlock basicTable">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>            
<td><label for="fos_user_registration_form_email" class="required">mailaddress:</label></td>
<td><input type="email" id="fos_user_registration_form_email" name="fos_user_registration_form[email]" required="required"/>
 <font color=red></font></td>
</tr>

<div id="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword"><div>
<label for="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_first" class="required">password:</label>    
<input type="password" id="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_first" name="fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword][first]" required="required" />
</div>

<div>
<label for="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_second" class="required">confirm:</label>
<input type="password" id="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_second" name="fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword][second]" required="required" /></div></div>

<div style="text-align:center;">
    <button style="height:50px;width:200px;" type="submit">submit</button>
</div>

</form>
```

somhow,it doesnt jump to the next page.....when I put submit button,just password '****' is disappeared and nothing happenes.

Comment: could you please describe `it doesn’t submit the pages` ? I guess you're getting a validation-error for the form because of the missing username parameter?

Comment: I guess you are right. Simply I deleted the username filed,it doesnt show validation-error.Now I confirmed it shows the validation-error,where can I set the validation parameter? It could be hint for me. I couldn't find.

Answer (score 1):

In you app/config.yml use these settings:

```
fos_user:
    use_username_form_type: false
```

Comment: I have tried this ,however it says 'ServiceNotFoundException: The service "fos_message.recipients_selector" has a dependency on a non-existent service "fos_user.user_to_username_transformer"'